# Has the FAA banned FPV for model aviation?

Tags: faa-regulations, model-aircraft

On the [FAA website](https://www.faa.gov/uas/model_aircraft/) the FAA says that you should not fly your model aircraft out of line of sight. Does this mean you cannot use [FPV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-person_view_%28radio_control%29) goggles?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The FAA has [interpreted the rules](https://www.faa.gov/uas/media/model_aircraft_spec_rule.pdf) to mean that the operator must have a line-of-sight view of the model aircraft at all times, and that **FPV does not qualify**.

> Based on the plain language of the statute, the FAA interprets this
>   requirement to mean that: (1) the aircraft must be **visible at all
>   times to the operator**; (2) that the operator must use his or her own
>   **natural vision** (which includes vision corrected by standard eyeglasses
>   or contact lenses) to observe the aircraft; and (3) **people other than
>   the operator may not be used** in lieu of the operator for maintaining
>   visual line of sight.

But also note that this does not apply if:

> ...the aircraft is operated in accordance with a community-based set of
>   safety guidelines and within the programming of a nationwide
>   community-based organization;

The above is from the linked NPRM released in June 2014. [The latest NPRM from February 2015](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/rulemaking/media/021515_suas_summary.pdf) has the same requirements.

So members of an organization like [AMA](http://www.modelaircraft.org/) are exempt from that rule. The AMA [requires a spotter](https://www.modelaircraft.org/files/550.pdf) to be used when flying FPV.

Comment: The current AMA FPV rules are also functionally similar to the FAA rules (since your spotter needs to be next to you and ready to assume Visual Line-Of-Sight control of the aircraft). So basically no cross-country FPV flights unless you and your spotter are being driven around in a truck following the model aircraft.

Comment: `unless you and your spotter are being driven around in a truck following the model aircraft` - There is actually an FAI competition class that is endorsed by the AMA for RC gliders called F3H (Cross Country Soaring) where pilots follow their gliders being driven around in a truck. So it's not completely unheard of.